# Is it possible to set scope for ng-include without using a directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to set scope on `ng-include` without using a directive or `ng-repeat`?

Example (for `$scope: { startEvent: {…}, recentEvents: [{…}, {…}, …] }`)

```
<h4>Start</h4>
<!-- how do I make event = startEvent here? -->
<ng-include src="'event-template'"></ng-include>

<h4>Recent</h4>
<ol>
  <li data-ng-repeat="event in recentEvents">
    <ng-include src="'event-template'"></ng-include>
  </li>
</ol>

<script id="event-template" type="text/ng-template">
  <time datetime="{{event.sendDate}}">{{event.sendDate}}</time>
  <span>{{event.description}}</span>
</script>
```

I want first include to have a scope `event` property set to `startEvent` -- `ng-repeat`  does it for me with `recentEvents`, but using `ng-repeat` over a single item would be a hack.

Obviously I can make a directive, but currently the whole thing is one small file.
With directive and directive template it would expand to three, and all to reuse a very small fragment.

Note that `ng-init` wouldn't work because it is executed at a different time I think.

Comment: I've seen the `ng-repeat="event in [startEvent]"` approach used for this purpose. It also creates a child scope. Yes, it's a hack :) I created a directive for my own use that creates an isolated scope for the element that it is applied to, specifically for `ng-include` cases that don't warrant a special directive.

Comment: @NewDev Yep if I had to create a directive it would at least seem reasonable to create a reusable one for small includes. Is your code for that open source?

Comment: Sure, let me put it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the `ng-repeat="event in [startEvent]"` approach used for this purpose. It also creates a child scope.

Yes, it's a hack :)

I created a directive for my own use that creates an isolated scope for the element that it is applied to, specifically for `ng-include` cases that don't warrant a special directive.

Feel free to re-use: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5w7fhBNtjL9fiUC4WQdO)

Comment: Thanks! I got some issues (10 $digest() iterations reached) when I tried to use inline object with Angular 1.1.5. So I did something different: http://plnkr.co/edit/v0VsB0I2V1qwPycca3yY?p=preview -- do you see any issues with it?

Comment: Hmm... I was going to say that it broke 2-way binding, but mine messes up the parent value altogether

Comment: So, it looks like it was fixed in [v1.2.5 fix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/43072e3812e32b89b97ad03144577cba50d4b776). I fixed what I previously broke in my version - it allows for 2-way binding.

Comment: Hmm, so this solution doesn't update if top level value has changed, unless the change was on subobject (e.g. updating `prop.name` in $timeout does not update names in isolated scopes). So basically if `startEvent` is set later it would not be applied to the child scope. However I do not think I required it in my question, so I'll just accept it)

Comment: One suggestion though -- if you add your directive code to the answer, it would be useful for future readers as there is no guarantee plunker link will still be valid let's say 2 years in the future.